# Get the argument value of a partialised function

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

Given the following toy example:

```r
library(purrr)
foo = function(x, a) x + a
foop = partial(foo, a = runif(1))
foop
```

```
<partialised>
function (...) 
foo(a = runif(1), ...)
```

I would like to know what the value of `a` is only using the `foop` object.

One way I found out was:

```r
e = as.list(environment(foop))
rlang::eval_tidy(e$args$a)
```

```
[1] 0.05872499
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do this. `partial` converts all arguments in `...` into `quosures` without going through any evaluation. That means you need to evaluate an argument to get its value, or you can only get its expression. Also, since `quosure` is an `rlang`-specific object structure, there is no better way than using `tidy_eval` to evaluate that. Perhaps what you have found out is what you can do best.

Comment: If you just want to save some keystrokes, then perhaps you can do `rlang::eval_tidy(environment(foop)$args$a)`

Comment: Note that the value you obtain in this way is not guaranteed to match the value that will be generated when the function is actually called. The reason is that the expression involves random number generation, but it will not be evaluated until it is needed. The only reliable way to capture the exact value of `a` used is to have `foo` store it internally and then return it as part of its output. P.S. This is not a concern for deterministic expressions that always evaluate to the same value.